What is the theoretical Head of a centrifugal pump when an infinite number of vanes are asssumed?
I came across this question in my Fluid Machinery Course:
A centrifugal pump of 1.25 m diameter is designed to pump
1.5 m3/s through 75 m height, whilst running at a speed of 600
rpm. At outlet the vanes are set back at an angle of 25° with
tangent to the wheel. If the measured shaft power is 1325 kW
and the pump has an effective circumferential area of 0.4 m² at
outlet, work out:
(i) theoretical head with the assumption of
infinite number of vanes,
(ii) theoretical head with the
assumption that the net power imparted to water flowing
through the impeller gets transformed into head without any
hydraulic loss, and
(iii) hydraulic and overall efficiencies if
external mechanical loss is equivalent to 45 kW and the
leakage loss amounts to 4%.
Here what conditions are we to assume when infinite number of vanes are to be considered ?

With an infinite number of infinitely thin vanes, I suspect you are simply to assume that the rpm is the same and that pressure is a function of the radial distance from the rotor's axis (no need to consider pressure and suction sides of a rotor).
